# Filling in Missing Entries in CSV File Using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am programming in Python3 using Sublime Text 3.

I have a csv file with 8 columns, two of which are empty. After reading the file using pandas, I am iterating through the rows, taking data from the current row, and then using that data to fill in the two empty entries in that same row.

Can I write the data in the row as I am going, or would I need to create a completely different file to store the newly completed csv file, and how should I go about doing so?

Comment: You may want to check `df.ffill(axis=1)`

Comment: You can write the data in the rows as you are going. But making a new csv will be great. Because in case of code failure you don't have to run the whole code again just read the new csv you created and work on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can write data as you are iterating itself. Try something like this

```
column = df['a'] * df['b']
df['c'] = column.where(df['c'] == np.nan, others=df['c'])
```